# .Net MVC web app - how to dynamically store multiple inputs (within one property) - DatabaseFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-database-first

I may have phrased my question in not the best of ways but here is the problem. I have a table in my View: https://ibb.co/0fXwfPn

Here is the code for said table in the .cshtml : https://ibb.co/qgRjQM6

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover row col-md-12 tablelightgrey">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeRole, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeTelephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeRole, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeTelephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeRole, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeTelephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingAttendee.MeetingAttendeeEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control detailsTextBox" } })</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If all the rows in the table are populated, only the first row contents are stored within the Name,Role,Telephone, Email properties. I get this, as all the properties are the same.

I was thinking perhaps an array of strings, but the trouble is, this application is built on the old school way of DataBase first model (edmx file which then generates the model).

So I created the table manually in SQL Server, and then the auto generated class is as : https://ibb.co/T19xrDQ

Now I cannot change anything within this class as its an auto generated class. I was thinking of a string of arrays.

Just trying to think how I can solve this? Each row of that table needs to be saved within one row of my database table - https://ibb.co/N3Ww5mm   so I cannot string.join all the values to save into on db column.

TIA

Comment: You can use the list of models it's the correct way to input multiple and while submitting time you can add range

Comment: So literally a List<MeetingAttendee> myList to get the user inputs from the view, but how would I go about saving that list to my table? For example, I could have 3 objects in my List (corresponding to 3 rows in the table that the user has filled out), but this database first approach just expects one object

Comment: Have you used Entityframwork?

Comment: I have for model first approaches,  but not for database first approach. There are no migrations in this project for example

Comment: No i want to know you are store data in database using Entityframwork?

Comment: Yes I believe so, the context class has all the models in a DBSet, example:

public virtual DbSet<MeetingAttendee> MeetingAttendees { get; set; }

And in the POST controller we are doing something like:

                    this.db.Referrals.Add(referral.Referral);
                    //this.db.MeetingAttendees.Add(referral.MeetingAttendee);
                    this.db.SaveChanges();

Comment: this.db.Referrals.AddRange(listOfModel)
you have to just change Add to Addrage else you can run for loop

Comment: thank you that makes sense i will give that a try